# The `val` in the for range is not immutable?

Tags: kotlin

In documentation, `val` is **assign-once (read-only) local variable**. However, below is a for loop that assigns values to `x` several times. Is it a different concept than C++ `const`?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = 6
    val y = 9
    for (x in 1..y) {
        println("fits in range $x")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
fits in range 1
fits in range 2
fits in range 3
fits in range 4
fits in range 5
fits in range 6
fits in range 7
fits in range 8
fits in range 9
```

Comment: the variable name is shadowed. and you found that you can't reference the outer variable `x` in loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The `x` used in the *range* construct is shadowing the `val x = 6`** - those are two different variables in two different scopes.

You can see that yourself by writing:

```
val x = 6
val y = 9
for (x in 1..y) {
    println("fits in range $x")
}

println(x)
```

The last call will print the original value - `6`

Comment: I confused [this official tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#using-ranges) using `for` instead of `if` while typing. Anyway, thanks!